# How to play facebook video in UIWebView or WKWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, html5-video, wkwebview

I'm trying to use facebook's embedded video player in a UIWebView.

The following code works in chrome, safari, mobile safari and firefox but does not play when loaded in a UIWebView or WKWebView

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bhanengtattoo/videos/vb.100000856281223/967837953254738/?type=3" data-width="500" data-show-text="false">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/bhanengtattoo/videos/967837953254738/"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bhanengtattoo/videos/967837953254738/"></a><p>Some placholder text</p>Posted by <a href="#" role="button">Bhaneng Venus</a> on Friday, 30 October 2015</blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

App Transport Settings are configured to allow arbitrary loads and on inspecting the webview after loading I can see that the facebook sdk has been downloaded and some processing of the video div has occurred, which includes an iframe now being embedded in the div. There are no js errors in the console and no blocked requests.

Any suggestions on how to get this working or debug it further much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was loading the html from a file hosted locally within the app rather than a web server. The following post seems to suggest the facebook js uses the url of the request and that loading a local file will cause problems.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1683961658522966/

I was able to work around the problem by loading the webview with base url set to "http://anythinghere.com". The video player now works as expected.